# Dimple.JS Animate line series animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to implement charts using Dimple.js and below is the code that i am trying to animate both the series (Bar and Line here) separately but it looks like line series animates like bar series (from bottom to top). However, i was expecting more like animation performed in here: http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

```
<div id="divBarWithLineChart" class="DimpleChart"></div>


    var width = $('#divBarWithLineChart').width();

    var height = $('#divBarWithLineChart').height();

    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#divBarWithLineChart", width - 20, height);

    d3.json("Scripts/Data/Data.json", function (data) {
        // Filter the data for a single channel
        data = dimple.filterData(data, "Channel", "Hypermarkets");

        // Create the chart
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
        myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 470, 300)

        // Add an x and 2 y-axes.  When using multiple axes it's
        // important to assign them to variables to pass to the series
        var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Brand");
        var y1 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Price");
        var y2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Value");

        // Order the x axis by sales value desc
        x.addOrderRule("Sales Value", true);

        // Color the sales bars to be highly transparent
        myChart.assignColor("Sales", "#222222", "#000000", 0.1);

        // Add the bars mapped to the second y axis
        myChart.addSeries("Sales", dimple.plot.bar, [x, y2]);

        // Add series for minimum, average and maximum price
        var min = myChart.addSeries("Min", dimple.plot.line, [x, y1]);
        min.aggregate = dimple.aggregateMethod.min;

        myChart.setMargins("70px", "30px", "70px", "70px");

        myChart.assignColor("Sales", "#083f65", "#083f65", 1);
        myChart.assignColor("Min", "#c62828", "#c62828", 1);

        myChart.staggerDraw = true;
        myChart.ease = "bounce";
        myChart.draw(1000);
```

Is it possible to animate line series separately? Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would like to know if its possible to this, please let me know if you find out. Also, I think order to do something like that you have to modified from d3.js probably, because dimple.js didn't have anything about this on documentation.

Comment: can someone please help me find the solution? or we can no way animate the line chart either using Dimple.JS or D3 directly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  If you inspect the svg line in the chrome developer bar, it's an svg path which can be animated with css...the path class name is dimple-line.  So just add a bit of css for this class name and when the line is drawn it mimicks the d3 example exactly (tried it at my site http://dimplejs.org) and it worked perfectly...

```
<style>
    .dimple-line {
        stroke-dasharray: 1000;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

or for a dashed effect try this...

```
.dimple-line {
        stroke-dasharray: 20;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
        to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
    }
```

See this site for other variations of this technique...https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/